# How to configure Debezium Mysql connector to produce primitive key instead of struct or json object?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using Debezium to detect changes in MySql source tables.   How can I produce Kafka messages such that the key is a numeric (`Long`) value instead of a Json object?

What I am getting:

```
key: {"foo_id": 123} 
value: {"foo_id": 123, "bar": "blahblah", "baz": "meh......"}
```

What I want:

```
key: 123
value: {"foo_id": 123, "bar": "blahblah", "baz": "meh......"}
```

My FOO table looks like this:

```
foo_id: INT
bar: VARCHAR 
baz: VARCHAR
```

Note that I am not using avro and I've experimented with several combinations of below (w/ and w/o key transformers) but failed to get the `Long` key.

```
"transforms": "unwrap,insertKey,extractKey",
"transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
"transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false",
"transforms.insertKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
"transforms.insertKey.fields":"foo_id",
"transforms.extractKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
"transforms.extractKey.field":"foo_id",        
"key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false", 
"value.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
```

I am not sure ValueToKey or ExtractField works for (MySQL) Source but I am getting below NPE.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.applyWithSchema(ValueToKey.java:85)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.apply(ValueToKey.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:44)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
```

Answer (score 3):

Found out a solution based on this https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-689

```
{
...
    "config": {
    "transforms": "unwrap,insertKey,extractKey",
    "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false",
    "transforms.insertKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.insertKey.fields":"foo_id",
    "transforms.extractKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractKey.field":"foo_id",        
    "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true", 
    "value.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "include.schema.changes": "false"  <-- this was missing
    }
}
```

Now, I am seeing the foo_id as an `Integer` (not a big deal it's not `Long`)  :)